# Vertically position material icon besides paragraph text

Tags: html, css

I have a p element, besides which I am placing a material icon via font method.

Both are inline-block to display side by side, but I am having trouble moving the icon vertically without breaking neighboring layout.

I have tried wrapping the icon in a div, span, and playing with making its container positioned relatively/absolutely but cannot seem to make it behave.

Simplified example for my project:

html

```
<div class="card-heading">
  <p>
    my title
  </p>
  <div class="icon-holder">
    <i class="material-icons">camera</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

scss

```
.card-heading {
  p {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .icon-holder {
    display: inline-block;

    i {
      padding-top: 6px;
    }
  }
}
```

Example codepen illustrating issue https://codepen.io/joshuaohana/pen/dRqgye

In this example, I am trying to move the icon down by 6px, but instead of moves both the p and the icon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `vertical-align` to center the icon.

```css
.card-heading p {
  display: inline-block;
}
  
.card-heading .icon-holder {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">

<div class="card-heading">
  <p>
    my title
  </p>
  <div class="icon-holder">
    <i class="material-icons">camera</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: didn't know `vertical-align` works on `inline-block`

Comment: Just tried it instinctively. But I am not sure if older browser support it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `display: flex` to `.card-heading`. Need to remove the `padding-top: 6px` from `.icon-holder`.

[Codepen here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bRxmBG).

Read more about CSS Flexible Box [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

```css
.card-heading {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: flex;
  
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -moz-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.card-heading p, .card-heading .icon-holder {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">

<div class="card-heading">
  <p>
    my title
  </p>
  <div class="icon-holder">
    <i class="material-icons">camera</i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hah brilliant thank you... I keep forgetting that I should always try out a flex solution whenever I run into a css problem :)